# $_SESSION storing array values is returning to other pages as string

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have PHP code setting a value in `$_SESSION`:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["token"]["token_name"] = "some value";
```

i've tried:

```
$_SESSION["token"] = array("token_name"=>"some value");
```

and the result is the same

Then i visit another page I have set up where I start the session and try to retrieve the value:

```
session_start();
$val = $_SESSION["token"]["token_name"];
echo $val;
```

The output is:
`s`

Looking at the saved session in `/tmp (my saved session directory)`:

```
token|s:10:"some value";
```

I'm sure the `|s` should be `|a` for array (`|s` I'm sure means string). I think the value is being incorrectly stored in the session file but i'm not sure why.

Other applications installed (3rd party) are working with arrays in the session variable and it is working correctly. I'm not sure if they are setting up session handling differently than me but i'm just using the defaults for the server.

**Edit**
This code runs fine on two other servers i've tried it on.

**Edit 2**
I changed the name from $_SESSION["token"] to $_SESSION["tokn"] and everything magically started working as it should. I have no idea why the server doesn't like me to use "token" in the name of an array occurrence of the $_SESSION variable but that did the trick. I'll chalk it up to a ghost in the machine :)

Comment: Just close the token brackets at another page :)

Comment: the closing bracket was a typo in this post. Sorry about that, i've fixed it in the original post.

Comment: Is that the whole code on the page that's setting the session variable? My guess is you have something else on that page that's making a reference to the session variable and reassigning it.

Comment: No, i made two scripts with the exact code listed in the post. I made the same comment below but I've tried this on 2 other servers and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the syntax here is wrong...

```
$val = $_SESSION["token"["token_name"];
```

It should be

```
$val = $_SESSION["token"]["token_name"];
```

Comment: sorry that was just a typo in this post. the error is still happening. thanks.

Comment: Why the negative? We was not supposed to know that.

Comment: You should know that if he left out a bracket he would get a syntax error, not an incorrect string value.

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
$val = $_SESSION["token"]["token_name"]; //missing square bracket
echo $val;
```

Comment: sorry i've fixed that. that's not my problem though i made an error while typing this document. thanks.

Comment: @user2148950 what do you get if you vardump $val above?

Comment: the var_dump is: string(1) "s"

Comment: Odd, is there any other code executing that could affect the session?

Comment: No, i made two scripts with the exact code listed in the original post. btw, the code executes perfectly on two other servers i've tried it on.

Answer (score -1):

```
//UPDATE SESSION WITH ARRAY
$_SESSION["token"]["token_name"][] = $val;
```

Then on the other page:

```
$newval = $_SESSION["token"]["token_name"];
echo $newval;
```

Comment: This would make `$newval` an array, so you would have to do `echo $newval[0];`. But I don't think he wants an extra level of array there.

Comment: I went ahead and tried it and it did create another level to the array. This stores seemingly correctly in the /tmp session file. This does not fix my original error. i prefer not to have another level added to the array as a solution to the problem. thanks.

Comment: I tried your code on my site and it works perfectly, really strange. I guess the next thing would be to look around your other code for anything that may be causing it to change.